# SessionID not retaining same value through a session

Tags: asp.net

I have a strnge problem which I dont know how to resolve.

The sessionID keeps changing every time I open a page in the application.
But when I debug the program, the sessionID remains constant and does not change

The application is installed on Windows server 2008 R2 (iis 7.5 and dotnet framework 4.0)

`<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="60" />`

What is the matter?

Note: This works fine on my local development machine.

**EDIT**

This is the code in Global.asax.vb for Session_Start`

```
      Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Session("mySessions") = "junk"
        AddMySessions()

        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            Dim sql As String

            sql = String.Format("SELECT EmpID FROM Intranet_Employees WHERE Username='{0}'", sUserName)
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            ' Production ...
            Session("EmpID") = CType(Dao.ExecuteScalar(cmd, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("cSqlTemplateDB")), String)
            Dim oEmpInfo As New TOrders.Data.Objects.Employee(Convert.ToInt64(Session("EmpID")))
            Session("EmpInfo") = oEmpInfo

            If Application("SessionCount") Is Nothing Then
                Application.Lock()
                Application("SessionCount") = 0
                Application.UnLock()
            End If

            Application.Lock()
            Application("SessionCount") += 1
            Application.UnLock()
        Else
            Response.Redirect("http://intranet/tsystem")
        End If

    End Sub


      Private Sub AddMySessions()
        Dim sMsg As String = Session.SessionID & ";" & Now.ToString & ";" &       Request.ServerVariables.Get("AUTH_USER").ToString

        If IsNothing(Application("mySessions")) Then
            Dim arrSessions As New ArrayList

            arrSessions.Add(sMsg)

            Application.UnLock()
            Application("mySessions") = arrSessions
            Application.Lock()

            arrSessions = Nothing
        Else
            Dim arrTemp As ArrayList = CType(Application("mySessions"), ArrayList)

            arrTemp.Add(sMsg)

            Application.UnLock()
            Application("mySessions") = arrTemp
            Application.Lock()

            arrTemp = Nothing
        End If

        sMsg = Nothing
    End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than week of frustration, I finally figured it out. The issue was not with the code or web.config -  but with the naming of the Server. The server name contained the underscore '_' which was blocking cookies. The server name was changed and everything worked fine. 
@fnostro - Thanks for your patience and suggestions.

Here is the link from microsoft.
`http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q316112`

Answer (score 3):

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx):

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate
>   storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a
>   result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the
>   session object is accessed. **If your application requires a static
>   session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the
>   Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store
>   data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code
>   in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the
>   Session object**.
>
> If your application uses cookieless session state, the session ID is
>   generated on the first page view and is maintained for the entire
>   session.

Comment: So what is the correct value. I have tried values of true, false, autodetect, uri for cookieless attribute and still get the same problem. It works when I run it through the debugger.

Comment: It's not your webconfig that needs adjusting.  you just need to *use* Session storage.  Read the paragraph - it tells you 2 ways to set a fixed ID

Comment: The Session_start is already implemented. I have added it to the question above.

Comment: When debugging, can you set a breakpoint within Session_Start and see it hit?  Generally speaking, Session_Start() isn't called until the session object is used.

Comment: Also, to clarify: I'm referring to Session_Start() in Global.asax not Global.ascx as you added to your post

Comment: Sorry! It is in the Global.asax.vb and yes I set a breakpoint within Session_Start() and it got hit. But like I stated before, when I run the app through the debugger, the session ID remains static.

Comment: ok - one last silly question: is the Global.asax file in your project match your published site?

Comment: Yes. Visual Studio is installed on the server too. So I am able to debug from the server.

Comment: found this in SO, something else to check.  In your web.config. do you have an `<httpCookies>` entry with `requireSSL="true"` ?  if so, and you don't make an https request, this apparently also will cause that session issue.

Comment: I dont have both in the web.config

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I fugured it out. It had to do with the servername containing an underscore which was blocking cookies

Comment: Those are the worst type of bugs.  Great job on finding that.